# compass -v fails on CentOS using ruby 1.9.3 installed with rvm

Tags: ruby, centos, rvm, sass, compass-sass

OS: Centos 5.8
Ruby version 1.9.3 (installed via RVM)

output from compass -v

```
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:22:in `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:213:in `default_gemfile'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:164:in `root'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:123:in `load'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `setup'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.0/bin/compass:25:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/compass:19:in `load'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/compass:19:in `<main>'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

gem list reports

```
bundler (1.1.5)
chunky_png (1.2.5)
compass (0.13.alpha.0)
fssm (0.2.9)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.3)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
sass (3.2.0.alpha.275, 3.1.20)
```

Comment: do you have `Gemfile` or `$BUNDLE_GEMFILE` ?

Comment: I uninstalled rubygems-bundler and re-installed compass and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstall rubygems-bundler and re-install compass